# Bitmap disappears when window is resized

Tags: c, visual-studio, bitmap, mfc

I have a simple GUI that is supposed to display an image when I am on a certain tab. I have the WM_PAINT message inside the tab process as shown below

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
            PAINTSTRUCT psLOGO;
            RECT rcLOGO;
            HDC hdcLOGO;
            //Prepares for painting window
            hdcLOGO = BeginPaint(hwndMonitor, &psLOGO);
            //Retrieves the coordinates of the windows client area
            GetClientRect(hwndMonitor, &rcLOGO);
            //creates a copy of the memory device context 
            HDC hdcDoubleLOGO = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcLOGO);
            HBITMAP Logo = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));         //Get a bitmap of the picture to be updated
            HBITMAP bmOldLOGO = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcDoubleLOGO, Logo);                                 //Get a handle to the image being replaced
            BitBlt(hdcLOGO, 0, 0, rcLOGO.right, rcLOGO.bottom, hdcDoubleLOGO, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);   //Bit block transfer of the bitmap color data

            SelectObject(hdcDoubleLOGO, bmOldLOGO);
            DeleteDC(hdcDoubleLOGO);
            EndPaint(hwndMonitor, &psLOGO);
            DeleteObject(Logo);
        break;
    }
```

hwndMonitor is the handle for that particular tab page

The image shows when I open the tab, but if I resize the window, or if I minimize and reopen the GUI, the image will disappear

I have to go to another tab and back to that tab to get the image back

Am I doing something wrong in my WM_PAINT message?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure all the calls are succeeding?

Comment: I did, I added a break point in the beginning of the WM_PAINT, and stepped thru the message code. It looks like all the variables are being initialized and used correctly.

I did notice that when I reopen the GUI, it only makes one call to WM_PAINT...but when I switch through tabs it makes two calls to WM_PAINT. Is the message supposed to be sent twice?

Comment: That sometimes happen because the parent tab window and the children windows overlap. Try adding the flag `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` to the parent tab control. Alternatively try `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` on the tab pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to react to the WM_SIZE message also. Resizing a window does not release a paint message.

On WM_SIZE just call:

```
InvalidateRect(hwnd,&rect,TRUE);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);
```

rect is a rectangle with the current window size. Invalidate marks the rectangle for a repaint, and UpdateWindow secures it is repainted immediately.

Comment: It's generally not necessary to call `UpdateWIndow`, it's more efficient to allow the invalidation to create a `WM_PAINT` as necessary.